# Can we manage multiple highchart charts in a single function by changing type in chart drawing functionm

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts, grep

Is possible to group types of charts in high charts.?

I have `json` data, which I want to express in chart type. And also there is range slider.I need to give a option to select chart type by the end user. I have a dropdown list in which I populate some chart types like `bar,pie,line` etc. when user selects an option that corresponding chart type should be displayed.  Is that possible with `highchart`?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rahulsankarer/BqHLz/

```
    Highcharts.setOptions({
                    chart: {
                        borderWidth: 5,
                        borderColor: '#e8eaeb',
                        borderRadius: 0,
                        backgroundColor: '#f7f7f7'
                    },
                    title: {
                        style: {
                            'fontSize': '1em'
                        },
                        useHTML: true,
                        x: -27,
                        y: 8,
                        text: 'Report'
                    }
                });

                var blogComments = [
    {
        "Name": "John",
        "Month": "Jan",
        "TotalWorkingDay": 12,
        "Attendance": 1,
        "Leave": 1
    }, {
        "Name": "John",
        "Month": "Feb",
        "TotalWorkingDay": 8,
        "Attendance": 2,
        "Leave": 1
    },
    {
        "Name": "John",
        "Month": "March",
        "TotalWorkingDay": 10,
        "Attendance": 0,
        "Leave": 0
    },
    {
        "Name": "John",
        "Month": "April",
        "TotalWorkingDay": 11,
        "Attendance": 0,
        "Leave": 0
    },
    {
        "Name": "John",
        "Month": "May",
        "TotalWorkingDay": 8,
        "Attendance": 0,
        "Leave": 1
    },
    {
        "Name": "David",
        "Month": "Jan",
        "TotalWorkingDay": 8,
        "Attendance": 2,
        "Leave": 3
    },
    {
        "Name": "David",
        "Month": "Feb",
        "TotalWorkingDay": 5,
        "Attendance": 1,
        "Leave": 0
    },
    {
        "Name": "David",
        "Month": "March",
        "TotalWorkingDay": 4,
        "Attendance": 2,
        "Leave": 0
    },
    {
        "Name": "David",
        "Month": "April",
        "TotalWorkingDay": 1,
        "Attendance": 1,
        "Leave": 0
    },
    {
        "Name": "David",
        "Month": "May",
        "TotalWorkingDay": 8,
        "Attendance": 2,
        "Leave": 0
    },
    {
        "Name": "Sam",
        "Month": "Jan",
        "TotalWorkingDay": 7,
        "Attendance": 0,
        "Leave": 0
    },
    {
        "Name": "Sam",
        "Month": "Feb",
        "TotalWorkingDay": 6,
        "Attendance": 0,
        "Leave": 0
    },
    {
        "Name": "Sam",
        "Month": "March",
        "TotalWorkingDay": 11,
        "Attendance": 0,
        "Leave": 0
    },
    {
        "Name": "Sam",
        "Month": "April",
        "TotalWorkingDay": 9,
        "Attendance": 0,
        "Leave": 0
    },
    {
        "Name": "Sam",
        "Month": "May",
        "TotalWorkingDay": 2,
        "Attendance": 0,
        "Leave": 0
    }
    ];
                var newSeriesTotalWorkingDay = {
                    name: 'TotalWorkingDay',
                    data: []
                };
                var newSeriesAttendance = {
                    name: 'Attendance',
                    data: []
                };
                var newSeriesLeave = {
                    name: 'Leave',
                    data: []
                };
                var userNames = [];
                var userNameMonths = [];
                $.each(blogComments, function (index, User) {
                    // get the series
                    newSeriesTotalWorkingDay.data.push(User.TotalWorkingDay);
                    newSeriesAttendance.data.push(User.Attendance);
                    newSeriesLeave.data.push(User.Leave);
                    // Get the usernames
                    if (userNames[User.Name]) {
                        if (userNames[User.Name]['months']) {
                            userNames[User.Name]['months'][User.Month] = User.Month;
                        }
                    } else {
                        userNames[User.Name] = {
                            'months': []
                        };
                        userNames[User.Name]['months'][User.Month] = User.Month;
                    }
                });
                //console.log(userNames);

                var newCategories = [];
                    for (var name in userNames) {
                        if (userNames.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
                            var tempObj = {}
                            tempObj.name = name;
                            tempMonths = userNames[name]['months'].sort();
                            tempObj.categories = [];
                            for (var month in tempMonths) {
                                tempObj.categories.push({
                                    name: month
                                });
                            }
                            newCategories.push(tempObj);
                        }
                    }

                window.chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                    chart: {
                        renderTo: "chart-more",
                        type: "column"
                    },
                    series: [newSeriesTotalWorkingDay, newSeriesAttendance, newSeriesLeave],
                    xAxis: {
                        categories: newCategories
                    }
                });

<div>
            <label>Select Chart Type :</label>
            <select>
              <option value="line">Line</option>
              <option value="area">Area</option>
              <option value="bar">Bar</option>
              <option value="audi">Audi</option>
            </select>
        </div>
```

Comment: i want a dropdown list when selecting one option that corresponding chart type will be displayed. here iam used hardcoded data but instead that i need to supply json data .how can i use it..please give me ideas..please

Comment: try this link to know how to send data in json to highchart. http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/preprocessing-data-from-a-file-csv-xml-json

Comment: it worked with json data..but i need to do it with a dropdown where user select a chart type that corresponding type want to be drwa. how can i mangae diffrent type chart in single function..?? is there any possible to set the "type" like an option...please reply

Answer (score 0):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/Umx5X/

Here I have demonstrated how you can listen to both the `select` change event and a `click` on the images to change the chart `type` dynamically.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var initialChartType = 'area';
    $('#top10_update').val(initialChartType);
    var chartSelector = '#top10';

    function changeChartType(myType) {
        $(chartSelector).highcharts().series[0].update({
            type: myType
        });
    }

    $('#top10_update').on('change', function () {
        var type = $(this).val();
        changeChartType(type);
    });

    $('.set-chart').on('click', function () {
        var type = $(this).data('chart-type');
        changeChartType(type);
    });


    $(chartSelector).highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: initialChartType,
            margin: [50, 50, 100, 80]
        },
        title: {
            text: 'TOP10'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: ' '
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['1', '2', '3', '4'],
            labels: {
                rotation: -45,
                align: 'right',
                style: {
                    fontSize: '13px',
                    fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                }
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Ilość'
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return '<b>' + this.x + '</b><br/>' +
                    'Ilość: ' + this.y;
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Ilość zgłoszeń, TOP10',
            data: [1, 2, 3, 43],
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                rotation: -90,
                color: '#FFFFFF',
                align: 'right',
                x: 4,
                y: 10,
                style: {
                    fontSize: '13px',
                    fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                }
            }
        }]
    });

    function ajax_update(date) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "index.php/ajax",
            async: false,
            method: 'post',
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                date: date
            },
            beforeSend: function () {
                $('#loading').show();
                $('#top10').highcharts().showLoading();
            },
            success: function (dane) {
                $('#top10').highcharts().xAxis[0].setCategories(dane.top10.xlabel, false);
                $('#top10').highcharts().series[0].setData(dane.top10.data);
                $('#top10').highcharts().setTitle(null, {
                    text: 'Dane za: ' + date.replace('^', ' - ')
                });

                $('#top10').highcharts().hideLoading();
                $('#loading').hide();
            },
            error: function (dane) {
                alert(dane.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to visit our demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/tZUp4/

which uses a `series.update`